# MVC - Saving a new user to a custom table when register

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

So I have an MVC Entity Framework app in which I created an `AppUser` model to which users will be added, along with adding them in the AppNetUsers as MVC does automatically.  This is the model's properties:

```
AppUserID As Integer    'primary key
FirstName As String
LastName As String
Email As String
User As ApplicationUser  'relate an AppUser to ApplicationUser stored in AppNetUsers
```

I try to add a user to this table when they register, like so...this is in the Account Controller:

```
' POST: /Account/Register
<HttpPost>
<AllowAnonymous>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Public Async Function Register(model As RegisterViewModel) As Task(Of ActionResult)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {
            .UserName = model.Email,
            .Email = model.Email,
            .FirstName = model.FirstName,
            .LastName = model.LastName
        }
        Dim newUser As New AppUser() With {
        .FirstName = model.FirstName,
        .LastName = model.LastName,
        .Email = model.Email,
        .User = user
        }
        Dim result = Await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)
        If result.Succeeded Then
                db.AppUsers.Add(newUser)
                Await db.SaveChangesAsync()
                Await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)
```

I run into a problem at the line `db.SaveChangesAsync()` - it throws a `DbEntityValidationException` saying "The User Name '[email]' is already taken."  As if it is trying to re-add the same user as an ApplicationUser as well???

If I comment out that line, it does not throw an error, but the new user is not saved to AppUsers, either.

How can I successfully add a new user to this additional table?

NOTE:  This `AppUsers` table is in the same Context as `AppNetUsers`.

---

**UPDATE:**

What I tried doing was creating a scaffolded Controller for the AppUser model, and calling the Create function there from the Register Post.

So this is Register Post now:

```
' POST: /Account/Register
<HttpPost>
<AllowAnonymous>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Public Async Function Register(model As RegisterViewModel) As Task(Of ActionResult)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {
            .UserName = model.Email,
            .Email = model.Email,
            .FirstName = model.FirstName,
            .LastName = model.LastName
        }
        Dim newUser As New AppUser() With {
            .FirstName = model.FirstName,
            .LastName = model.LastName,
            .Email = model.Email,
            .User = user
        }
        Dim result = Await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)
        If result.Succeeded Then
            Await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)
            Dim controlThis = New TestWebApplication2.Controllers.AppUsersController
            Await controlThis.Create(newUser)
            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
        End If
        AddErrors(result)
    End If
    ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

And this is AppUser Create Post:

```
    ' POST: AppUsers/Create
    <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Async Function Create(ByVal appUser As AppUser) As Task(Of ActionResult)
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.AppUsers.Add(appUser)
            Await db.SaveChangesAsync()
            'Go to Home index instead of AppUsers index
            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
        End If
        Return View(appUser)
    End Function
```

This does pass `newUser` to Create as expected, and looks like it should be fine...but I'm still getting the exact same error at `Await db.SaveChangesAsync()`.  What is up with that?

---

**NEW UPDATE:**

OK - So I had the thought maybe I need to do this the other way around.  So I created a `CreateAppUserViewModel` which is exactly the same as the RegisterViewModel.  I made the Create view for AppUser the same as the Register view, except that is uses `CreateAppUserViewModel` and posts to Create in AppUsersController instead.  When you click Register, it goes to Create AppUser view.  And this is the Create Post:

```
    Async Function Create(model As CreateAppUserViewModel) As Task(Of ActionResult)
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {
                .UserName = model.Email,
                .Email = model.Email,
                .FirstName = model.FirstName,
                .LastName = model.LastName
            }
            Dim newUser As New AppUser() With {
                .FirstName = model.FirstName,
                .LastName = model.LastName,
                .Email = model.Email,
                .User = user
            }
            db.AppUsers.Add(newUser)
            Await db.SaveChangesAsync()

            Dim controlThis = New AccountController()
            Dim result = Await controlThis.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)
            If result.Succeeded Then
                Await controlThis.SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)

                'Go to Home index instead of AppUsers index
                Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
            End If
            'controlThis.AddErrors(result)
        End If
        ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

NOW - the User IS added to the AppUsers table.  BUT, drilling into the line

> Dim result = Await controlThis.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)

I get error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Which occurs in AccountController here:

```
Public Property UserManager() As ApplicationUserManager
    Get
        'This line is what I'm being told is what throws the error:
        Return If(_userManager, HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)())
    End Get
```

I'm not exactly sure what is not referenced that it doesn't like.  When I put my code back to using the standard Register Post in AccountController, the parameterized `New` sub is never used, and `_userManager` says it's "Nothing" in both cases.

Note that a new row is added to `AspNetUsers` table with the username, email and User ID. But the rest remains NULL.

Any ideas what else I need to do if this is the way to make it work?  Thank you!